# Error when trying to apply git diff, "No valid patches in input"

Tags: git, powershell, git-patch

I'm creating a powershell script with the goal of going through several git branches, saving a patch of the working changes, switching to the trunk branch to pull remote commits, then switching back to the working branch and reapplying the working changes.

Here is the method I am testing specifically:

```
git diff > test.patch
git restore .
*do main branch operation*
git apply test.patch
```

However when I try to apply the patch that I have just created I get an error:

> error: No valid patches in input (allow with "--allow-empty")

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Git version:  2.35.2.windows.1

Powershell version: 5.1.19041.1320

Comment: Most likely PowerShell has corrupted the patch by turning it into UTF-16-LE. You can, however, get similar effects by forcing the `git diff` command to use color. This is why robust scripts avoid `git diff` and use instead the various plumbing commands.

Comment: UTF-16 was my issue. From powershell you can fix it with `Get-Content .\my.patch | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 .\myutf8.patch`

Comment: when i do this in bash, it takes my color codings that are applied to the normal diff, so the patch is corrupt, and dos2unix wont resolve it.  e.g. i see a bunch of `[1;33m` at the line beginnings.  Turns out it was my alias setup, which i used `gd` by muscle memory but `git diff` worked fine.. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem as well when applying the patch. When I opened the patch, I got the patch with UTF-16 LE BOM encoding. Quite likely this was the problem.

So instead of using

```
# don't do this
git diff > myoldpatch.patch
```

for creating the patch of unsaved changes, using Powershell, you do this instead (thanks benf!)

```
git diff | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 .\goodutf8.patch
```

PS. tried in git 2.42

Comment: An alternative is to create the patch from Windows Command Prompt (cmd.exe).

Comment: This worked! Apologies for taking so long to accept it

Answer (score 29):

> Likely windows changed the line terminator to CRLF. Get it back to LF.

For anyone else struggling - I tried this, but I also had to re-save the patch file in UTF-8 format for git to recognise it.

Comment: For me, CRLF was not an issue. But the format was and saving it in UTF-8 helped.

Answer (score 10):

I also had the same problem, but I got it solved, use Notepad to open the patch file, select UTF-8 in the code selection, then save it, and then use git apply patch to enter the patch

Answer (score 3):

Likely windows changed the line terminator to CRLF. Get it back to LF.

Comment: it would be nice if you had added _how_ to actually do that...

Answer (score 1):

In my case the reason was the external diff helper set in git config, so specifying the `--no-ext-diff` flag helped

Comment: dude you just saved my day! I used `difftastic` and it was messing with `git diff`!